# Count the TOTAL number of categories in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, count, categories

With or without posts within. I need to display the total number of categories in my Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to count category is:
1) firstly fetch all category from wordpress
2) count them using simple php funciton 
 complete code will be like:

```
<?php $args = array( 'parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0 );

$categories = get_categories( $args );

echo "Total categories : ".count( $categories );    ?>
```

i used this code always :)

Comment: It appears this will only count top level categories and not include child categories.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
$args = array(
'get' => 'all',
'hide_empty' => 0
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );
echo count( $categories );    
?>
```

Comment: When using `get => all` the `hide_empty => 0` is redundant, but will still work.

Answer (score 0):

A more straight forward way (perhaps faster?)

```
global $wpdb;

$categories_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->terms" );

echo "<p>Categories count is {$categories_count}</p>";
```

Comment: Not everything in the `wp_terms` table is a category

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve list of category objects [get_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/):

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <?php
  $categories = get_categories();
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $i++;
    echo '<li class="list-group-item"><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '"><span class="text-muted float-left">' . $category->category_count . '</span>' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: It appears this will only include non empty categories and does not count them.